# Problem downloading python 3

Tags: 16.04, python3, reinstall

While updating my nvidia drivers I got a warning about inconsistent python 3 package and the advise to reinstall python 3.

Searching the forum gave me another post with the exact same warning ([Python 3 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914556/python-3-not-working)) and a nice solution by David Foerster https://askubuntu.com/a/914589/672852.

However, after trying this:

```
sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3 python3.4 python3-minimal python3.4-minimal libpython3.4-minimal
```

I got the following notice:

```
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd 
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar
Let op, 'libpython3.4-minimal' wordt geselecteerd omwille van de regex 'python3.4'
Let op, 'libpython3.4-minimal' wordt geselecteerd omwille van de regex 'python3.4-minimal'
Pakket libpython3.4-minimal is niet beschikbaar, hoewel er naar verwezen wordt door
een ander pakket. Mogelijk betekent dit dat het pakket ontbreekt,
verouderd is, of enkel beschikbaar is van een andere bron
E: Pakket 'libpython3.4-minimal' heeft geen kandidaat voor installatie
```

And for the non-Dutch speakers:

```
Package libpython3.4-minimal is not available [...]
E: Package 'libpython3.4-minimal does not have a candidate for installation.
```

The question being: how do I reinstall Python3 now?

Oh yes, this problem started after a fresh install of 16.04. And I did the fresh install due to problems with the 17.04 upgrade.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 and also 17.04 have `python3.5` instead of `python3.4`, so I suggest you try your command again, replacing all occurrences of 3.4 with 3.5.

Comment: @ByteCommander
Great, download worked. Unfortunately the next step:
`sudo dpkg -i *python3*.deb`
gives me the following errors: 
- no access to archive, file or folder doesn't exist.
- error found while processing *python3*.deb

Comment: You don't need to manually install any .deb packages for Python. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @ByteCommander
Well, I'm a novice and just following the instructions from someone more experienced.  
Does your comment mean I don't have to do anything else after downloading?

Comment: Yes, I just looked at David's answer and the second command block with the `dpkg` and stuff is only "If this doesn't work". So at the `sudo apt install -f --reinstall ...` seems to have worked in your case, you should be done.

Comment: Converted my first comment into an answer so that you can accept it if it solved your problem.

Comment: @ByteCommander Ah, thnx! It seems to have solved the main problem. There is some leftover error but I better create a new question for that.

Comment: Okay, good. Feel free to leave me a comment here with the link to your new question as soon as you have posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 and newer versions have `python3.5` instead of `python3.4`, see [these search results on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3).

Therefore I suggest you try your command again, replacing all occurrences of `3.4` with `3.5`:

```
sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3 python3.5 python3-minimal python3.5-minimal libpython3.5-minimal
```